# How to play a mp3 file and delete

Tags: sound, scripts, directory, delete, mp3

I am looking for a script where I could play a mp3 file using mpg123 and delete or not the file. I would like to listen for few seconds and jump to next file after decide if it will be or not deleted. Someone could help?

Comment: Hi Leandro, *if* the answer solved your problem, as you indicated, would you consider to accept the answer (tick the big "V" below the up/down arrows on the left). It is the appropriate way to indicate the answer worked for you.

Answer (score 2):

The script below will play a sample of 5 seconds of all mp3 files inside a directory in a row, asking you if the file should be deleted or not after each sample.

[image]

After proceeding, the script will produce a report like:

```
--------------------
remove: /home/jacob/Bureaublad/test/04 Suite Espanola Nr. 1 Op. 47 Nr. 4.mp3
keep: /home/jacob/Bureaublad/test/08 Danzas Espanolas Op. 37 Nr. 3.mp3
remove: /home/jacob/Bureaublad/test/02 Suite Espanola Nr. 1 Op. 47 Nr. 2.mp3
```

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import os
import sys
import time

dr = sys.argv[1]
report = []

for f in [f for f in os.listdir(dr) if f.endswith(".mp3")]:
    file = os.path.join(dr, f)
    subprocess.call(["timeout", "5", "mpg123", "--quiet", file])
    try:
        subprocess.check_output([
            "zenity",
            "--question",
            "--text=Delete?",
            ]).decode("utf-8").strip()
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        report.append("keep: "+file)
    else:
        os.remove(file)
        report.append("remove: "+file)

print("-"*20)
for l in report:
    print(l)
```

#### How to use

1. Unnecessary to say, but install `mpg123:

   ```
   sudo apt install mpg123
   ```
2. Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `filter_mp3.py`
3. Run it with the targeted directory as argument:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/filter_mp3.py /path/to/folder
   ```

#### Explantion

The script:

- lists all `mp3` filse in a directory:

  ```py
  for f in [f for f in os.listdir(dr) if f.endswith(".mp3")]:
      file = os.path.join(dr, f)
  ```
- plays them for 5 seconds:

  ```py
  subprocess.call(["timeout", "5", "mpg123", file])
  ```
- runs a `zenity` question dialogue:

  ```py
  try:
      subprocess.check_output([
          "zenity",
          "--question",
          "--text=Delete?",
          ]).decode("utf-8").strip()
  except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
      report.append("keep: "+file)
  else:
      os.remove(file)
      report.append("remove: "+file)
  ```

  The dialogue will raise a `subprocess.CalledProcessError` if user either clicks <kbd>No</kbd> or closes the window (nothing happens), or will close error free if user chooses <kbd>Yes</kbd>.

  In the latter case, the file will be removed:

  ```py
  os.remove(file)
  ```

Comment: Instead of starting and killing mpg123, you could use the `timeout` command (or use the more versatile `ffplay`, but since OP asked for mpg123...)

Comment: @muru ah, great, thanks! Will edit if I get home.

Comment: Thank you for your help !!! It worked... I have just made a few change to use only the keyboard.

Comment: Hi @LeandroFranco Great! *if* the answer solved your problem, as you indicated, would you consider to accept the answer (tick the big "V" below the up/down arrows on the left). It is the appropriate way to indicate the answer worked for you.